# Dense Number Sequence

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, number-theory, primes

OEIS: [A167171](https://oeis.org/A167171)

A *dense number* is a number that has exactly as many prime divisors as non-prime divisors (including 1 and itself as divisors). Equivalently, it is either a prime or a product of two distinct primes. The first 100 dense numbers are:

```
2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 26, 29, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 46, 47, 51, 53, 55, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 74, 77, 79, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 89, 91, 93, 94, 95, 97, 101, 103, 106, 107, 109, 111, 113, 115, 118, 119, 122, 123, 127, 129, 131, 133, 134, 137, 139, 141, 142, 143, 145, 146, 149, 151, 155, 157, 158, 159, 161, 163, 166, 167, 173, 177, 178, 179, 181, 183, 185, 187, 191, 193, 194
```

Given a nonnegative integer `n`, output `dense(n)`. `n` may be 0-indexed or 1-indexed.

### Reference implementation (Sage)

```py
import itertools

def dense_numbers():
    n = 1
    while True:
        prime_divisors = [x for x in divisors(n) if x.is_prime()]
        non_prime_divisors = [x for x in divisors(n) if not x.is_prime()]
        if len(prime_divisors) == len(non_prime_divisors):
            yield n
        n += 1

N = 20
        
print itertools.islice(dense_numbers(), N, N+1).next()
```

[Try it online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVkMEKwjAMhu-FvkOOLZPhPAp7hZ28iQy0GQa6dLSdzre3m8qm4sGfHkr-9sufUNs5H4Ei-uicDVJIYbABgxyw5r49og9Kb6WAJIYSisf1eiaLsPM9Pr1RnacWa0MXCs6H9Hg_QOM8DEAMr7JiDdTAkFOopw9KH2YEO67_wbCLv1DJtcjqnaahLKfydyO9mGTUjdAa4EU2yKb5pahSqM16dqRIKF7sMSWydEL1sccVVOlkhc4Zh6j0HWNmcbU=&lang=sage)

Comment: So many prime number sequences... I didn't know so many *existed*

Comment: @βετѧΛєҫαγ There are also primes called [Sexy Primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexy_prime) ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°).

Comment: @Adnan Oh myy ;D

Comment: What is the maximum value for `n`?

Comment: @R.Kap As high as your language of choice can go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ÆE²Sḍ2µ#Ṫ
```

Reads from STDIN and uses 1-based indexing. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w4ZFwrJT4biNMsK1I-G5qg&input=&args=MjE)

#### How it works

```
ÆE²Sḍ2µ#Ṫ  Main link. No arguments. Implicit argument: 0

      µ#   Read an integer n from STDIN and execute the chain to the left for
           k = 0, 1, 2, ... until n of them return a truthy value.
           Return the array of matches.
ÆE           Compute the exponents of k's prime factorization.
  ²          Square each exponent.
   S         Compute the sum of all squares.
    ḍ2       Test if 2 is divisible by the result (true iff  the sum is 1 or 2).
        Ṫ  Tail; extract the last (n-th) matching value of k.
```

Answer (score 1):

### 05AB1E, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

1-indexed

```
µ             # while counter != input
 NÑ           # get divisors of current number
   p          # check if prime
    D         # duplicate
     O        # sum one copy
      s_O     # invert and sum the other copy
         Q½   # if equal increase counter
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wrVOw5FwRE9zX09Rwr0&input=MTAw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 17 bytes

```
:1yt.
1<.=$p#dl<3
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OjF5dC4KMTwuPSRwI2RsPDM&input=MTAw&args=Wg)

#### Predicate 0 (main predicate)

```
:1yt.
:1y     Find the first (input) solutions of predicate 1
   t    Last element
    .   Unify with output
```

#### Predicate 1 (auxiliary predicate)

```
1<.=$p#dl<3
1<.            1 < output
  .=           assign a value to output
  . $p#d       output's prime factorization contains no duplicate
        l      and the length
         <3    is less than three
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 12 bytes

**All credits to Dennis for [his algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89990/48934).**

```
`w♂N;*2%Y`╓N
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=YHfimYJOOyoyJVlg4pWTTg&input=MTAw)

```
`w♂N;*2%Y`╓N

`        `     define a function
 w             prime factorization in exponent form:
               18 = (2^1)*(3^2) becomes [[2,1],[3,2]]
  ♂N           get the last element (exponent) of each sublist
    ;*         dot-product with self; equivalent to squaring
               each item and then taking the sum
      2%Y      test divisibility by 2
          ╓    first (input) solutions to the above function
           N   get the last element.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
!fö`¦2ṁo□LgpN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/XzHt8LaEQ8uMHu5szH80baFPeoHf////DQ0MAA)

### Explanation

```
!fö`¦2ṁo□LgpN
            N List of natural numbers
 fö           filtered by the following 4 functions:
          gp  prime factorization, grouped into equal runs
      ṁo□L    get length of each run, square and sum
   `¦2        is 2 divisible by the sum?
!             nth element in filtered list
```

Comment: Divisible by 2 can just be [less than 3](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/XzHt8DYb44c7G/MfTVvok17g9///f0MDAwA)

Comment: for some reason, `<3` still requires an extra increment `→` at the end, maintaining the same byte count. @JoKing

Comment: ah, i guess `<3` includes `1`, which throws off the indexing

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `rG`, 56 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7 bytes

```
λ∆ǐ²∑2Ḋ;ȯ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJyRz0iLCIiLCLOu+KIhseQwrLiiJEy4biKO8ivIiwiIiwiMTUiXQ==)

port of jelly

Answer (score 0):

## R, 93 Bytes

```
dense=function(n){a=b=0;for(i in which(!n%%1:n))if(which(!i%%2:i)+1==i)a=a+1 else b=b+1;a==b}
```

It has a tendency to throw a warning. Its not really a problem. Allowing the warning saves me 5 bytes.

Ungolfed

```
dense=function(n){
     a=b=0                                #Initializing
     factors = which(!n%%1:n)             #Finds all factors
     for(i in factors)                    #Loops through factors
         prime = which(!i%%2:i)+1==i      #Tests if current factor is prime. If it is -- the first term in this vector will be TRUE. Otherwise, it will be false.
           if (prime) a=a+1 else b=b+1    #If first term is true, add 1 to a. Else add one to b. 
      return(a==b)                        #Test equality of a and b.
}
```

Comment: Can't you use the `+=` operator to save 2 bytes?

Comment: Sadly, R doesn't have any useful incrementation operators like `+=` or `a++`. Sometimes there can be shorter ways (taking advantage of loop structure mostly), but I don't know of one here.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 79 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=2:n<1or-~f(n-(sum((k%i<1)+2*(k%i**2<1)for i in range(2,k))<3),k+1)
```

Uses 1-based indexing. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ZWtXW6).

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 118 Bytes

```php
for($i=1;!$o=$s[$argn];$r[2]?:$t+=2*$$i=1,$t?:$s[]=$i)for($t=0,$r=[],$n=++$i;$n;$n--)$i%$n?:$t+=${$r[]=$n}?:-1;echo$o;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#JYwxC8IwFIT3/gvhhNY2YOvW56ODdHDRxS2EIlLbLEl5zSb612uscMtx33fHZhqnpBfx0kk/eQnWDemn7S7X2/nUZpTgLoPj8kDL00sKyyVt4BmzXhdDEF2ZpkbIudrhBxQIsc/aMGy2WoH3BYS1KeA4z2EJLkapDHYL97fxilfRce@mViX1j9HD07J8AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 102 bytes

```
f(n:PI):PI==(i:=1;repeat(i:=i+1;a:=divisors(i);2*#[x for x in a|prime?(x)]=#a=>(n=1=>break;n:=n-1));i)
```

ungolf and result

```
-- 1 base Indexed: return the n_th number i that has 2*#divisorsPrimeOf(i)=#divisors(i)
ff(n:PI):PI==
     i:=1
     repeat
        i:=i+1
        a:=divisors(i)
        2*#[x for x in a|prime?(x)]=#a=>(n=1=>break;n:=n-1)
     i

(3) -> [f(i)  for i in 1..23]
   (3)  [2,3,5,6,7,10,11,13,14,15,17,19,21,22,23,26,29,31,33,34,35,37,38]
                                               Type: List PositiveInteger
```